# Can't change text in button

Tags: javascript

Here is the code from the book "HTML 5 + JS for Dummies", looking at it for more than 2 hours and can't find a reason why it doesn't want to work. I'm in very early stage and sorry for my newb question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Outputting data to HTML </title>

<script language ="JavaScript">


{
document.getElementById("myText").
innerHTML ="Clicked!";
}
</script>
</head>



<body>
<h1> Creating HTML Element Output </h1>
<div> <p id="myText">Change Me </p> </div>

<div> 

<input id="btnClickMe"
type="button"
value = "Click me"
onlick="WriteText()"/>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do youn want to change the text of the p element or of the button? Your code and question are inconsistent regarding this.

Comment: Your right, i don`t understand the code right, the text to change should be above the button  from "Change me" to "Clicked"

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Outputting data to HTML </title>

<script>

function WriteText()
{
document.getElementById("myText").
innerHTML ="Clicked!";
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<h1> Creating HTML Element Output </h1>
<div> <p id="myText">Change Me </p> </div>

<div> 

<input id="btnClickMe"
type="button"
value = "Click me"
onclick="WriteText()"/>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what i did/what was wrong:

1. You have used wrong syntax for functions or you forgot to use the function keyword
2. You misspelled onclick (onlick)
3. <del>I moved the script part out of the head</del>

Comment: Thank you! When  i was writing from the book seems i have eaten the main function  WriteText().  Very stupid but i barely understand what i`m doing at the moment..   For the 'On Lick" hahaha.. would you advise some editor that highlights the misspelled code? Using Dreamweaver CS5, but it didn`t highlight.  Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: The point three is wrong. The script should preferably be in the head. If it's not in the head it should be in the body, it should definitely *not* be between the head and body elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use setAttribute method because input filed have not innerHTML property.

```
`<script language ="JavaScript">
function WriteText()
{
document.getElementById("myText").setAttribute("value", "Clicked!");
}
</script>
</head>
```

`

Comment: It's not the `input` element that is being changed, it's a `p` element.

Comment: your code is not wrong. you not define function name in javascript. so please define you function in javascript. like.: `function WriteText()
{
document.getElementById("myText").
innerHTML ="Clicked!";
}`